# Is it OK to stop a thread from the owning objects Dispose method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispose

Here is a simple example:

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    bool working;
    public MyClass()
    {
        working = true;
        Thread t = new Thread(Worker);
        t.Start();
    }
    void Worker()
    {
        while(working)
        {}
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        working = false;
    }
}
```

Is it okay to do this ? Will Dispose() even be called while the thread is still running? If not, how to better do it ?

Comment: seems fine to me.  except for the fact that you want to at least make the `working` variable `volatile`.  Otherwise, it's actually possible for your thread to never end even after you dispose `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dispose` will not be called unless you call it, either explicitly or through enclosing `MyClass` instantiation in `using` statement.

> Will Dispose() even be called while the thread is still running?

It can be called like:

```
using (MyClass m = new MyClass())
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

So once the `using` block ends, it will call the `Dispose` method in your class.

*(Although your variable should be [`volatile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) to indicate that the field might be modified by multiple threads)*

But the important thing to note is, that there is no magical thing about `Dispose`, even the `using` statement translates into `try-finally` , where `Dispose` is explicitly called in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on that your `Dispose` method will be called.

You can wrap you class instance with `WeakReference`. The thread should stop its work once the reference is garbage collected.

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    class CancellationSignal
    {
        WeakReference _reference;
        public bool IsWorking { get { return _working && _reference.IsAlive; } }
        volatile bool _working;

        public CancellationSignal(WeakReference reference)
        {
            if (reference == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("reference");
            _reference = reference;
        }

        public void Signal()
        {
            _working = false;
        }

    }

    CancellationSignal _cancellationSignal;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal(new WeakReference(this));
        Thread t = new Thread(Worker);
        t.Start(_cancellationSignal);
    }

    static void Worker(object state)
    {
        var s = (CancellationSignal)state;
        while (s.IsWorking)
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cancellationSignal.Signal();
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer to avoid using finalizers but I still have to say that another solution would be calling `Signal` in finalizer (and then you can remove `WeakReference` stuff):

```
 ~MyClass()
 {
    _cancellationSignal.Signal();
 }
```

Notice that `_working` is declared as volatile. You can also use `ManualResetEventSlim` or even [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

In both approaches (`WeakReference` and finalizer) you have to avoid passing `this` reference to Thread (because it would prevent your class instance from being garbage collected) therefore I added a `CancellationSignal` class and marked `Worker` as static.

Comment: I would have to see the code you're thinking about for the `WeakReference` idea.  But I suspect that both that, and the finalizer approach would not work, because in passing a delegate to the `Worker` method to the thread, that implicitly also passes a hard reference to `this` (the `MyClass` instance).  So, unless `Dispose` is called explicitly, I think that the thread would actually prevent the `MyClass` instance from ever getting garbage collected.  Haven't tried it though.

Comment: I would suggest having a publicly-exposed façade object targeted by the weak reference, and specify that the object's services are only guaranteed to run while strongly-held references exist to that façade.  Further, I would suggest having the "main" object provide a "nudge" method that can be called from the finalizer of the façade, which can be used to interrupt the main thread if it's waiting on something.  The inability to pulse a monitor without acquiring its lock makes things a little icky (the finalizer method should be able to return "instantly" after setting a flag even if...

Comment: ...the worker thread is busy for awhile, but should ensure that the worker thread will get pulsed even if the finalizer runs just before the worker thread does its "wait") but having the finalizer set the quit flag and then do a `TryEnter` with a short timeout should usually work okay; the only problem would be if the other thread was preempted between checking the quit flag and waiting, and such preemption was longer than the finalizer's timeout.  I don't think there's any nice way to solve that problem.